# Microsoft App Registeration, Authentication, and Redirect URL

Tags: javascript, angular, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

Using Angular 2+ with [@azure/msal-angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/README.md) library.

I have an app with the domain

> http://localhost:4200/userId/someOtherId

So it can be any of

> http://localhost:4200/2425/2532152
>
> http://localhost:4200/35235/152115

I have a button, Login with Microsoft. On clicking that button, I call the sign in method

```
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';

/// more code
signIn() {
    await this.msalService.loginPopup(environment.microsoft.scopes);
    //more code
}
```

(See sign in method here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/angular?tutorial-step=3 , I do the same thing)

Now, in the application registration portal, I have 
http://localhost:4200 as my redirect URI.

As a result, when I attempt to authenticate, I get the following error:

> The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls
>   configured for the application

My question is, how do I solve this problem? Someone said I should be passing in state &state=userId:someotherId, but how do I do that with [microsoft's authentication library for angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/README.md)?

Answer (score 1):

The UserAgentApplication accepts state as a property of the [options](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-core/src/UserAgentApplication.ts#L236) object in the constructor.

However, when they created [MSAL-Service](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/src/msal.service.ts#L28) which derives from UserAgentApplication it looks like they didn't expose the state parameter.  I would recommend opening an issue on the GitHub repo.

Comment: Ok, lets say I do pass state, then what?

Comment: @Asool If you assign state to MSAL, then when it calls the Authorization server it will pass the state along.  That state will be returned on the redirect URL.  You have to register all redirect urls.  So you would need to create a handler at the root of your site and then use the state that is passed back to you to redirect to the actually URL you want to reach.  I'm assuming it is not practical to register a reply-url for every user/someId

Comment: Thank you Darrel! That helps.